# Program terminates early in the child process if an array is inserted

Tags: c

So the problem I am having is that when the line "int pipefd[2]" is inserted into the program and it only reaches "Debug3" once and ends there. Nothing is written into the file too. Without the line the program is working. Where does the error come from? I see no connection between an 'int array' beeing declared and the for-loop that is executed in the child process.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    int pipefd[2];

    pid_t pid;
    int count;

    count = atoi(argv[1]);

    open("a.txt", O_CREAT);
    int fd = open("a.txt", O_RDWR);


    switch (pid = fork()) {
        case -1:
            printf("Failed to create child\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            break;

        case 0:;

            char *str;

            printf("Debug1\n");

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                printf("Debug2\n");
                sleep(1);
                printf("Debug3\n");
                sprintf(str, "Writer-PID: %d -> record-nr: %6d\n", getpid(), i);
                printf("Debug4\n");
                write(fd, str, strlen(str));

            }
            printf("Debug5\n");

            close(fd);

            break;

        default:

            wait(&pid);

            break;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: `char *str; sprintf(str, "Writer-PID: %d -> record-nr: %6d\n", getpid(), i);` Where do you think `str` points to? Your program has undefined behaviour as it writes to an uninitialised pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```c
char* str;
```

This defines `str` as a char pointer but does not give it a place to point to, nor does it allocate any memory for it. It is uninitialized. If you want to allocate some space with a known length, then you can just declare it as an array:

```c
char str[100];
```

If your length is not known at compile-time, then you should use `malloc` and `free`:

```c
char* str = malloc(size_to_allocate * sizeof(char));
// code here
free(str); // to avoid memory leak
```